# SwiftUI: disappearing popover on iPad only on some Views

Tags: swift, swiftui, popover

I am experiencing problem with .popover() in SwiftUI it sometimes works correct, and other times it just appear and immediately disappear. Logging value of isPresented binding variable seems to show correct value. 
Any idea why such thing can happen? 
Moreover I have the same AddAttachment button that has popover() call added to different screen views and in one it works ok in other it stops working. Adding logs to init() of this screen views shows that value of isPresented @Binding var is ok (it is called several times (init()) but there is isPresented == true all the time after tapping button that should show popover). If popover disappear then taping button again changes @Binding var to false (so nothing show), and second consecutive tap make popover to appear and again immediately to disappear.

Comment: can you add your code what you have tried so far ?

Comment: I can add but it is just simple .popover { }  on Button() where action: has self.isPresented.toggle() @State/@Binding. In some screens it works, in other i doesn't. I provide more code but I need to cutout interesing parts and it takes me some time.

Comment: due to your structural design of some view it mayn't visible .

Comment: Even if you think is simple, I would recommend to show some code. It might be way easier to understand than reading all the explanation and theory

Comment: I think this has to do with the popover being inside of a NavigationView. I posted a question and added a code sample: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64164584/swiftui-popover-disappears-when-its-inside-a-navigationview