# SwiftUI Popover Disappears When It's Inside a NavigationView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a popover inside of a NavigationView:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      NavigationLink(destination: ChildView()) {
        Text("Navigate")
      }
    }
    .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
  }
}

struct ChildView: View {
  @State private var popover = false

  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      Button(action: { self.popover = true }) {
        Text("Toggle")
      }
      .popover(isPresented: $popover) {
        Text("Yolo")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When you toggle the popover for the first time after starting the app, it immediately disappears. After that it works correctly. Is this a bug in NavigationView? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Not reproduced with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

Comment: I'm on Xcode 12 / iOS 14 as well, maybe it's only on the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Use sheet instead:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: ChildView()
            ) {
                Text("Navigate")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @State
    private var isPresented = false
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(
                action: {
                    isPresented.toggle()
                }) {
                Text("Present")
            }
        }
        .sheet(
            isPresented: $isPresented
        ) {
            Text("Yolo")
        }
    }
}
```